# Using Ansible and Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ping, configure, ansible

I just started using Ansible with Vagrant. I installed Ansible on my local dev and it seems to me that it works well. I created  in my project vagrant the inventory file in this manner:

```
vim inventory
testserver ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/user/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

Whith using the instruction mentioned below i have got this message:

```
ansible testserver -i inventory -m ping
testserver | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We    
recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to      
help diagnose the issue
```

What is the best way to configure ansible with vagrant ?
best regards.

Comment: rerun `ansible` with `-vvvv` and add that output.

Comment: i solved the probem : I had to give the statement on the same line without a jump : testserver ansible_ssh_host=ip ansible_ssh_port=my_port ansible_ssh_private_key_file=my_file

Comment: can you please add this as an answer and accept it: I've run into the same problem, and almost missed the solution as it was in comments

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has the same problem, the solution is using only one line, without backslashes. For instance

testserver ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key

Answer (score 0):

In Vagrant you can use the Ansible plugin, or (if it's not supported) fall back to the in-line provisioner. This way you don't need Ansible installed on the machine hosting the VM. Your Vagrantfile would look something like this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.define "mybox" do |mybox|
    mybox.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    mybox.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.15.101"
    mybox.vm.hostname = "mybox"
    config.vm.provision "shell",
      inline: "apt-get update && apt-get install python-software-properties -y && apt-get install software-properties-common -y && apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible && apt-get update && apt-get install ansible -y && cp /vagrant/hosts /etc/ansible/hosts"
    if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-ansible-local")
      config.vm.provision "ansibleLocal", playbook: "playbook.yml"
    else
      config.vm.provision "shell",
        inline: "ansible-playbook /vagrant/playbook.yml"
    end
  end
end
```

Ensure that `playbook.yml` exists in the same directory as the Vagrantfile.

- `vagrant up` will launch the VM and then install Ansible + run the playbook
- `vagrant provision` will re-run the playbook

Additionally, you can do `vagrant ssh` and run the playbook from within the VM with `ansible-playbook /vagrant/playbook.yml`.